# Searching a C++ string and strip off text if present

Tags: c++, string

I have to handle two types of string:

```
// get application name is simple function which returns application name. 
// This can be debug version or non debug version. So return value for this
// function can be for eg "MyApp" or "MyApp_debug".

string appl = getApplicationName();
appl.append("Info.conf");

cout << "Output of string is " << appl << endl;
```

In above code `appl` is `MyAppInfo.conf` or `MyAppInfo_debug.conf`.

My requirement is whether it is debug or non-debug version I should have  output of only one i.e., `MyAppInfo.conf`. How can we check for `_debug` in string and if present and how do we strip of that so that we always get output string as `MyAppInfo.conf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap `getApplicationName()` and call the wrapper instead:

```
std::string getCanonicalApplicationName()
{
    const std::string debug_suffix = "_debug";
    std::string application_name = getApplicationName();
    size_t found = application_name.find(debug_suffix);
    if (found != std::string::npos)
    {
        application_name.replace(found, found + debug_suffix.size(), "");
    }
    return application_name;
}
```

See the documentation for [`std::string::find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) and [`std::string::replace()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/).

Answer (score 1):

```
 string appl = getApplicationName(); //MyAppInfo.conf or MyAppInfo_debug.conf.
 size_t pos = appl.find("_debug");
 if ( pos != string::npos )
        appl = appl.erase(pos, 6);
 cout << appl;
```

Output is always:

> MyAppInfo.conf

See sample output : http://www.ideone.com/x6ZRN

Comment: Of course, if the debug suffix changes from `_debug`, you'll need to update the hard-coded `6`, too.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: True. But if it changes, then you've to modify `debug_suffix` string in your solution as well.

Comment: That was my point. One change in mine: two in yours. I think you're right to use erase() in this case.